# Invalid hostname error when connecting to s3 sink when using secret key having forward slash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flume

I have a **`forward slash`** in aws secret key.

When I try to connect to s3 sink

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid hostname in URI s3://xxxx:xxxx@jelogs/je.1359961366545
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Credentials.initialize(S3Credentials.java:41)
```

When I encode forward slash with `%2F`, I get

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

How should I encode my secret key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I end up creating a new secret key without forward slashes. This is a know issue and generating new key is only solution.

Answer (score 4):

samthebest solution works, you just have to add "" surrounding the keys. Here how to use it:

```
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId="yourkey" -Dfs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey="yoursecret" <your_hdfs_path> s3a://<your-bucket>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
-Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=<your-key> -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=<your-secret-key>
```

e.g.

```
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=<your-key> -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=<your-secret-key> -<subsubcommand> <args>
```

or

```
hadoop fs -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=<your-key> -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=<your-secret-key> -<subsubcommand> <args>
```

Comment: Please further explain your answer, don't post the snippets only.