# Hadoop distcp copy from S3: Signature does not match error

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hdfs

I am trying to copy a file from S3 to my hadoop HDFS on Amazon EC2.

The command that I am using is:

```
bin/hadoop distcp s3://<awsAccessKeyId>:<awsSecretAccessKey>@<bucket_name>/f1 hdfs://user/root/
```

- f1 is the name of the file
- I have also changed it to s3n to see if it    works but it does not.
- I replace the    forward slash in my secret access key with %2F

Error that I get is:SignatureDoesNotMatch

```
org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for '/%2Ff1'

<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>

<StringToSignBytes>...</StringToSignBytes>

<RequestId>...</RequestId>

<HostId>..</HostId>

<SignatureProvided>NsefW5en6P728cc9llkFIk6yGc4=\
    </SignatureProvided>

<StringToSign>GETMon, 05 Aug 2013 15:28:21 GMT/<bucket_name>/%2Ff1</StringToSign>

<AWSAccessKeyId><MY_ACCESS_ID><\ /AWSAccessKeyId></Error>
```

I have only one AWS Access Key Id and secret Key. I checked my AWS account and they are the same. I use the same AWS Access Key and secret Key to log on to my EC2 cluster. I have also tried using core-site.xml but that has not helped either.

Thanks,
Rajiv

Comment: I also found that you would need your s3 url to start with s3n instead of s3

Comment: this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681938/invalid-hostname-error-when-connecting-to-s3-sink-when-using-secret-key-having-f

Answer (score 1):

Regenerating my AWS Key and Secret such that there is no forward slash in my secret worked for me.
Ref: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3733

Comment: Unfortunately the plus sign will still cause the interface to fail

Comment: I've tried this and it still gives the same error, my new key contains a plus sign '+', which I'm not sure should be avoided again

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to regenerating the key that worked for me was to use -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId= -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey= flags when running distcp.

Example:
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId= -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey= s3n://path/to/log/dir hdfs://hdfs-node:8020/logs/

Note the use of s3n, which has a 5GB file limitation: [Difference between Amazon S3 and S3n in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569455/difference-between-amazon-s3-and-s3n-in-hadoop)

Edit: Do not url-encode the secret access key, so slashes "/" and pluses "+" should be passed as they are!

Comment: The last solution won't work, the hadoop file system still complaints: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS